# AWS lambda to assume role in the same aws account to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, assume-role

I have created a role to get objects from s3 bucket as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3GetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cat-pics/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Next, created a lambda function to assume this role. For that added the following statement to the basic lambda execution role which is attached to lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::same-account-id:role/AssumeS3RoleDemo"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the following code

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("this test should be printed")
    # create an STS client object that represents a live connection to the 
    # STS service
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

    # Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
    # ARN and a role session name.
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::same-account-id:role/AssumeS3RoleDemo",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession"
    )

    # From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary 
    # credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
    credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']

    print("credentials are")
    print(credentials)
```

does not work. I keep getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::same-account-id:assumed-role/lambda_basic_execution_new/AssumeRoleDemo is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::same-account-id:role/AssumeS3RoleDemo: ClientError
```

Here AssumeRoleDemo is name of the lambda function and AssumeS3RoleDemo is the role name which has access to S3.

Is it possible to assume role in the same account ? Is so, what step am I missing here ? Please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use STS and AssumeRole in your lambda code to access S3 if both are in the same account, if role attached to lambda has policy allowing access on S3 it will work just fine.

But if you really want to do it, you need to make sure your role `AssumeS3RoleDemo` trust policy allow lambda execution role to assume it.

Below is a link to one example using two different accounts, but the mechanism is the same using just one account:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Answer (score 2):

You need amend the role with [trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)

```
        {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
    }
```

In addition to that make sure your S3 bucket doesnt have a [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html). Because resource based policy and IAM based policies both should be allowing.

Comment: Are you sure lambda.amazonaws.com needs to be the principal here? I'd have thought the principal had to be the role which the lambda function is using. In this case the Role that the Lambda service is using is trying to assume the `AssumeS3RoleDemo` and not the Lambda service itself. The trust policy you showed is required for the lambda execution role.

Comment: What is see in the question is .. person trying to authenticate lambda for s3 permissions which are already present in IAM Role the user created. So instead of adding permissions manually to an IAM role or policy , here all we need is to attach trust policy to the role with s3 permissions because that's the recommended way from AWS.

Comment: From the way the roles are named I'd assume the main purpose of this setup is to create a demo that shows how to assume a role via python, which is why it's not particularly helpful to grant the original role the permissions to get access to the bucket, that would render the demo obsolete ;-) - Maybe @Ashy Ashcsi can shed some light on that.